# How to get the Git current branches and tags

Tags: git

I would like to set an alias for getting the ref names pointing at the current changeset (`HEAD`) or a given ref. The aim is to know "where are we?", "which branches and tags are equivalent (pointing at the same ref)?", "what is the current ref?", "where is the given ref compared to HEAD?".
Some of these informations are available using various Git commands and shown in most Git prompts.

Comment: *“where are we compared to HEAD”* – HEAD is always pointing to the currently checked out commit. If you were to compare with HEAD, you would just compare your working directory with HEAD, and do a `git diff`.

Comment: I meant "where is the given ref compared to HEAD" (when a ref is given as parameter). Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two following commands provides almost what I want:

```
id = log -1 --pretty=format:'%h%d'
id = show -s --pretty=format:'%h%d'
```

With the ability to give a ref as parameter, for instance:

```
$ git id 5.6.0
02a719d (some-tag, origin/master, origin/5.6.0, master, feature-NXP-9342-make_wizard_use_connect_client, 5.6.0)
```

Ideally, I would like to add some colors to differently highlight the current checkout ref (`.git/HEAD`), the tags and the local and remote branches. The reflog could be useful too (e.g `HEAD@{4}`).
For instance, in the above sample, `some-tag` would be yellow (color for tags), `origin/master` and `origin/5.6.0` would be blue (color for remote branches), `feature-NXP-9342-make_wizard_use_connect_client` and `5.6.0` would be green (color for branches) and `master` would be orange (color for the current HEAD). Any hints?

Comment: Shouldn’t this be an edit for your question instead of an answer?

Comment: That answer is not some complementary information or a modification of the question but an acceptable answer (even if not perfect or incomplete) I wanted to share with people asking the same question. I though it was clearer like this, rather than putting part of an answer inside the question.  
I'm still open to better answers or improvements to my own answer.

Comment: As of git 1.8.3 (May 24, 2013), the color issue is fixed with `%C(auto)`; use: `id = show -s --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h%d'`